# How to Swipe and delete selected table view row data from sqlite database in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I used fmdb sqlite database wrapper. I'm Confusing with getting selected row label texts. my confusion is, When i swipe and delete the `tableView` row then that entire row will be also will delete from database which has that `currentCell.userID.text`. so, how to do this? thanks in advance. 
code i have try,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index!) as! DashBoardCell
    print(currentCell.userID.text)  //I am getting  NiL

    let deletedID = currentCell.userID.text

    if editingStyle == .Delete
    {

        let tableData = indexPath.row

        items.removeAtIndex(tableData)
        number.removeAtIndex(tableData)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirPaths = filemgr.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

        databasePath = dirPaths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("visitors.db").path!

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: self.databasePath as String)
        if contactDB.open()
        {
            let deleteSQL = "SELECT * FROM VISITORLIST WHERE userid = '\(deletedID)'"
            let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(deleteSQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
            if !result
            {
                print("Failed To Delete Visitor Lists")
                print("Error3: ",contactDB.lastErrorMessage())
            }
            else
            {
                print("Successfully Deleted")

            }

        }
        else
        {
            print("Error4: ",contactDB.lastErrorMessage())
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`, you should just be using `indexPath`. Your current code it deleting the correct object from the table data but the wrong object (or nothing if no row is selected) from the SQLite store.

Comment: Yeah! You are correct. I just confused for selecting `indexpath` of `tableView`

Answer (score 1):

```
 let deleteSQL = "SELECT * FROM VISITORLIST WHERE userid = '\(deletedID)'"
```

Should be :

```
 let deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM VISITORLIST WHERE userid = '\(deletedID)'"
```

:)

Comment: Thanks Mr.Muhammed. I got `deletedID` is nil. is anyway to get `currentCell.userID.text` ?

Comment: Can you put your func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
} Method ?